# python unresolved attribute reference when using Type[class_name] instead of just class_name in type hinting

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, type-hinting

I would like to type hint an inheritance structure, but I don't know how to do it correctly. The idea is that function c can take any subclass of A. Some sub-classes have attributes that others don't and these are not defined in the parent class, but rather in the child class. Function c checks the subclass and if it's the right one uses a specific attribute of the class. In this setting PyCharm complains that this argument is not in the parent class.

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Type


class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a)
        self.b = a + 1


class D(A):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(D, self).__init__(a=a)
        self.d = a - 1


def c(arg: Type[A]):
    if type(arg) is B:
        print(arg.b)
    if type(arg) is D:
        print(arg.d)
```

Gives "Unresolved attribute reference 'b' for class A". Any recommendations?
Many thanks!

A further curious thing to me is that the below also complains about arg.a. when I use Type[A] rather just A in the hinting.

```py
def c(arg: Type[A]):
    if type(arg) is B:
        print(arg.b)
    if type(arg) is D:
        print(arg.d)
    print(arg.a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Type[A]` and `A` are not the same thing!  `A` means an instance of `A`, and `Type[A]` means the type of `A` -- in other words, the class itself.  Mypy is correctly complaining about your attempts to access `A.a` because `a` is an instance attribute and you've said the function doesn't take an instance!  :)

You want just:

```
def c(arg: A):
    if isinstance(arg, B):
        print(arg.b)
    if isinstance(arg, D):
        print(arg.d)
    print(arg.a)
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the clarification! Do you also know how to get it to stop complaining about trying to access arg.b in the case when arg.b is a property of B which is the subclass of A? Or is there a better practice way of doing this?

Comment: Using `if isinstance` or `assert` should narrow the inferred type within that scope; updated answer to show how you'd use `isinstance`.

Comment: Nice one, that works, thanks a lot! I will mark it as solving the problem. If it's not too much trouble, I'd like your take on what you think is best when you have three layers of inheritance and looking for the middle layer exclusively in the if statement. In that case isinstance() will be true for the lowest layer also. One way around this I can think of is using elif such that the lowest layer is the first condition in the if statement then the middle layer is an elif; that should assure that when it is true then the lowest layer is already false, but maybe you can recommend a better way?:)

Comment: If you want it to *specifically* be B I think you could use `if isinstance(arg, B) and type(arg) is B: ...`.  Or you could do `if type(arg) is B: assert isinstance(arg, B) ...`.  Or the `elif` as you suggest, depending on context.

Comment: I like your first suggestion, thanks for your help! :)